# Please help me to clarify a sentence on Ted talk

Tags: listening

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu4Yvq-g7_Y

At 14:04, he said that: 
"There are so great features on phone let us lemonade eliminate a lot of time"

Can anyone help me to declare what's his mean? "lemonade eliminate"? Or youtube is missing on the auto-generated transcript

Answer (score 5):

What he actually says is "There are so many great features on phones - on devices - that let us **liminate** - uh, **eliminate** - a lot of time we waste on devices."

He was speaking quickly and accidentally mispronounced *eliminate*. He then repeated himself with a correction. The auto-generated closed captions picked the mispronunciation up as "lemonade".

Comment: Yes, that's right. The auto-generated transcript is lacking in accuracy. He fumbles over his words and is saying "...that let us eliminate..."